# Why nodemailer is not working on Linux Server?

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, server, smtp, nodemailer

In localhost everything works fine. But when I deployed the code on Ubuntu Server, I am incurring an error:

> Error occurred while sending the email: Connection timeout

Here is my configuration:

```
host: "smtp.hostinger.com",
secure: true,
secureConnection: false,
tls: {
   ciphers: "SSLv3",
},
requireTLS: incutrue,
port: 465,
debug: true,
auth: {
   user: process.env.GRIEVANCE_EMAIL,
   pass: process.env.GRIEVANCE_EMAIL_PASSWORD,
,
```

**Let me tell again, in localhost I ain't incurring any error and recieving emails successfully.**

I tried running the same code in localhost again, it works fine there.